# rake db:migrate fails with the following trace

Tags: rake

Could someone please advise me on how to make sense of this rake trace and point me in the right direction to fix this problem? I've tried to do a rake db:migrate and then I receive an error message of 'rake aborted! cannot load such file -- ruby/debug/ide'.

I made sure that I had the ruby-debug-ide gem installed, run bundle install, and made sure I was on the right ruby version in rvm. When I ran the trace, this is what I got:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- ruby/debug/ide
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/home/dso/rails_projects/cams/src/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dso/rails_projects/cams/src/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/dso/rails_projects/cams/src/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/dso/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@cams/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to all who reply!

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard this question with my most humble apologies. Problem found in the GemFile. Another developer made a change in the GemFile that caused the problem. Going through a crash course on Rails for a new project :-)

Comment: You can just delete you question using the "delete" link underneath it, if you like =)